# How to update one collection in Mongodb based on other Json data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have collection in Mongo Db Like this

```
( [
   { EmployeeId: "123", qty: 100, status: "A"},
   { EmployeeId: "456", qty: 25, status: "A"},
   { EmployeeId: "789", qty: 85, status: "A"}
]);
```

Now i have other data coming from Json which contains EmployeeId in it Like below:

```
( [
  { EmployeeId: "123", Designation: "manager"},
  { EmployeeId: "456", Designation: "Lead"},
  { EmployeeId: "789", Designation:"Developer"}
]);
```

I want to update all the records in the first collection at once based on the EmployeeId which is common in Json and MongodB collection.

Is there any possibility to achieve that in NodeJs.

Comment: There are many ways to [process an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in Javascript. Choose your favorite one, and then set up the [MongoDB update method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with the proper query and operations.

Comment: If "at once" is your concern and you want a transaction based approach, the new MongoDB now supports transactions. Otherwise just loop on them and do single update operations.